# Qt simulate key press to control SimpleScreenRecorder application in Linux

Tags: keypress, qkeyevent, keyrelease

I want (in Linux) to control desktop recording by activating SimpleScreenRecorder with emulating key press CTRL+SHIFT+R.

[SimpleScreenRecorder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19tr1.png)

I tried this code:

```
QKeyEvent * eve1 = new QKeyEvent (QEvent::KeyPress,Qt::Key_R,Qt::ControlModifier|Qt::ShiftModifier,"r");
qApp->postEvent ((QObject*)this, (QEvent *)eve1);
QKeyEvent * eve2 = new QKeyEvent (QEvent::KeyRelease,Qt::Key_R,Qt::ShiftModifier|Qt::ControlModifier,"r");
qApp->postEvent ((QObject*)this, (QEvent *)eve2);
```

But this does not work.
I can send key press event to ui->lineEdit but a can't send it to another running application in this case SimpleScreenRecorder.

How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
 system("xdotool key \"control+shift+r\"");
}
```